# how to check if the toast have dismissed or not

Tags: android

i want to  check if the toast  have  dismissed  or not ,because user click the mouse the toast is show,but may me the user continuous click,so i need to check,i cannot use the dialog

Answer (score 17):

```
Toast toast = null;
if (toast == null || toast.getView().getWindowVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
    toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
        "Text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();
}
```

Check if the toast is visible before you show it again.

Comment: Showing toast `getWindowVisibility` returns `View.GONE` (6.0.1)

Answer (score 8):

```
Toast toast = yourToastCreationCode();

if (null == toast.getView().getWindowToken())
{
    yeahToastIsInvisible();
}
```

Comment: noe .. it will still be null if toast is created.. cant check visibility

Answer (score 5):

Based on Denis answer, but worked better for me.

```
Toast t;
t=Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
t.show;

if (t.getView().isShown())
{
   //visible
}
```

Comment: `isShown` doesn't work

Comment: According to the documentation isShown() "Returns the visibility of this view and all of its ancestors"
So this is not working