# Android show newest toast

Tags: android, android-edittext, toast

I'm working on my first `Android` application and I have a situation that really annoys me.

Lets say that user has to enter some information in few `Edit Text` fields and can't proceed if there is at least one empty field.

If user clicks a button to proceed and there is at least one empty field, a certain `Toast` is displayed.

The problem is, if user clicks that button like 10 times, and then enters those missing information and proceeds, those `Toast` messages keep showing in the new `Activity` along with `Toast` for successful registration.

Is there a way to interrupt a currently displayed `Toast` and display newest or something similar that will stop this kind of behaviour from happening?

edit: I have accepted @Vucko's answer because it suits better for my problem. @Augusto Carmo wrote the answer that indeed works, but I prefer Vucko's answer, it is just more elegant.

Comment: Heard about `editText.setError("Yo bro enter something");`? That is way better than a toast and it'll automatically solve your error.

Comment: @Vucko No, I haven't, till now. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Take a look at [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907863/how-to-check-if-the-toast-have-dismissed-or-not) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5295765/toast-issue-in-android) as well.

Comment: @KoltenSturgill those answers would solve this situation, but I wasn't aware of setError method, and it just seems more appropriate solution for this kind of problem.

I would say that setError is probably more friendly for device resource usage. Thanks tho!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The more elegant and common way to do this would be to use:

```
editText.setError("Your error message");
```

This will disappear itself once you write something in your editText or you can manually remove it by calling `setError(null);`.

Answer (score 3):

Have a single Toast object, and when you want to show another toast message, you cancel the last one and show the new one. Example:

```
Toast toast = new Toast();
toast.makeText(CONTEXT_HERE, MESSAGE_HERE, TIME_HERE).show();

// displaying another
toast.cancel();
toast.makeText(CONTEXT_HERE, ANOTHER_MESSAGE_HERE, TIME_HERE).show();
```

Comment: Thank you, but I think I will use approach @Vucko wrote, it just seems more elegant :)